# Is there input-block style like btn-block in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change width of input such as buttons that have **btn-block** style by bootstrap. For your better understanding, I take a photo from my project.

```
   <hr/>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">  
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control input-lg" id="email" placeholder="Enter number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

[**My project picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK3NB.png)

Comment: do you want to make width of your button same as width of your input field

Comment: @YadhuBabu, yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```html
 <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">  
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-2">
   <input type="email" class="form-control form-control input-lg" id="email" placeholder="Enter number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want input width same as button width.
Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txnn3rLx/) . Hope it gives you the idea. No need **column classes/div** inside the `form-group` class, it might not give you what you want

for your easy, i attached code here...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">  
              
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control input-lg" id="email" placeholder="Enter number">
                </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
                </div>
           
        </form>
 </div>

    </div>
```